# Running Guard Livereload in a Codio box

Tags: php, port, guard, livereload, codio

I am trying to run `guard-livereload` on my [Codio](https://codio.com/) box.

The problem is when ever I "run" the project I get a `CONNECTION_REFUSED` error in my browser console.

I am not sure what is doing this as I have changed the port into the Codio range and set the file to watch for PHP files:

```
# A sample Guardfile
# More info at https://github.com/guard/guard#readme

guard 'livereload', :port => '4000' do
  watch(%r{.+\.(css|js|html|php)$})
end
```

I also have included this file in all my pages:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://0.0.0.0:4000/livereload.js"></script>
```

When I run `guard` it is waiting for a browser to connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In codio box you have a domain name associated with your project: .codio.io, you can find it in IDE menu Project->Box Info. You should use it in your client code to include the livereload.js file. example (my bo domain is rebold-bogard):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://rebold-bogard.codio.io:4000/livereload.js"></script>
```

0.0.0.0 address is for binding on server side. By default guard binds 0.0.0.0, this mean nothing to change here, only think you should be mind of is a notification library, you should use libnotify to track codio changes.

Comment: Did try this, unfortunately I receive this error:
``Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)``
Have you got this working on your box?

Comment: Yes I had it working. but I had troubles with file watchers notification libraries. it didn't track changes from nano or codio, only from vim. Try grunt it worked for me fine for nodejs development.